# Removing the word "theorem" or defn from a listoftheorems

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

How can I remove the word theorem/defintion from a list of theorems:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{defn}

...

\listoftheorems

\begin{defn}[My definition]
  \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{defn}
```

Results into:

List of Theorems

1.1 Defn (MyDefinition)... 1

I would like have this:

1.1 My Definition ..........1

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess that “My Definition” is an exceptional definition, so I suggest trying something along the lines of (untested) `\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, name=My Definition]{mydefn}` followed by `\begin{mydefn} \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\] \end{mydefn}`.

Comment: @GuM I'm afraid I have quite a few definitions: around 15 I'd prefer a generic solution rather than defining 15 theorem types...

Comment: @JohnKormylo where do I set the gobble parameter?

Comment: Actually, the theorem style only affects the main text, not the \contentsline entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the code that adds the theorem name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thmt@mklistcmd}{\thmt@thmname}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thmt@mklistcmd}{\thmt@thmname}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thmtformatoptarg[1]{#1}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{defn}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems

\begin{defn}[My definition]
   \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thrmtools redefines `\contentsline` inside the `\listoftheorems`, adding an extra argument (the theorem name).  So I created a new theorem name for the sole purpose of adding things with `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{defn}
\declaretheorem{test}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignore=defn]

\begin{defn}[My definition]
\addcontentsline{loe}{test}{\string\numberline {\thedefn}My definition}%
   \[a^2 + b^2 = c^2\]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```